# Multiple Variable in a Single Form Field?

Tags: javascript, forms, field, var

Is there a way to display two number variables within a single field of a form? I'm trying to get my thr row to display var# to var#.

var thr = and the document.getelem need to change but I'm not sure to what? I'm brand new to javascript so I don't know the lines to use off the top of my head.

```
function calcheartrate() {
    var numage = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var minhr = (220 - numage) * .50
    var maxhr = (220 - numage) * .85
    **var thr = (minhr, "to", maxhr);
    document.getElementById("minhr").value = thr.toFixed(0);**
}
```

Comment: Please change `eval(document.getElementById("age").value)` to `+document.getElementById("age").value`. Eval is evil and you don't even need it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function calcheartrate() {
    var numage = document.getElementById("age").value,
        minhr = (220 - numage) * .50,
        maxhr = (220 - numage) * .85,
        rate = minhr.toFixed(0) + " to " + maxhr.toFixed(0);   

    document.getElementById("minhrs").value = rate;
}
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qnGY/

More about "Eval is Evil": https://www.google.com/search?q=eval+is+evil